# What can be an invariant of a function up to a polynomial?

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f$ be a (smooth) function on $[a,b]$. What would be "natural" in some sense invariant quantities of $f(x)+P_n(x)$, where $P_n(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, which don't depend on $P_n$?

Say, for the case $n=0$, $f(x)+P_0(x)=f(x)+C$,  one can take
$$
\max_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)-\min_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)\quad(*).
$$
What would be the analogues for higher degrees?

Of course, derivative $f^{(n+1)}$ is invariant, as well as taking differences. For example, $f(b)-2f(\frac{a+b}2)+f(a)$ would do for $n=1$. But this takes into account the ordering of points on the line. I'd prefer to have something more like (*).

Another way would be to take some norm $\|\cdot\|$ for functions on $[a,b]$ and consider
$\inf\limits_{P_n}\|f-P_n\|$, but that is not constructive and tastes tautologic to me.

Comment: It should just come down to "any function of $f^{(n+1)}$".  What is your goal with this question, though?  At the moment, it's not clear to me what type of answer would be acceptable here.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I've got a problem where to a solution function one can add a polynomial of a certain degree $n$. And for $n=0$ the quantity $\max_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)-\min_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)\quad(*).$ suits me fine. So I'm trying to find something like that for other values of $n$. I don't know that answer would be interesting here myself.  As for derivatives, they require smoothness. Besides the quantity mentioned, as well as infimum of  a norm seems not expressible as a function of derivatives.

Comment: It does require a certain amount of smoothness to invoke derivatives, but assuming that level of smoothness, all the invariant quantities are definitely functions of $f^{(n+1)}$ (and almost trivially so): Just define the linear operator $(T\phi)(x) = \int_a^x \phi(t)\,dt$ and note that $f-T^{n+1}f^{(n+1)}$ is a polynomial function of degree at most $n$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I don't understand, is there a way to obtain quantities like $\max_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)-\min_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)$ or  $\inf\limits_{P_n}\|f-P_n\|$ as functions of $f^"(n+1)}$?

Comment: It's just the fundamental theorem of calculus plus the theorem that $\phi^{(n+1)} = 0$ if and only if $\phi$ is a polynomial function of degree at most $n$.  Specifically,
$$\max_{x\in [a,b]} f(x) - \min_{x\in [a,b]} f(x) = \max_{x\in [a,b]} \int_a^x f'(t)\,dt - \min_{x\in [a,b]} \int_a^x f'(t)\,dt \\ \inf_{P_n}\|f-P_n\| = \inf_{P_n}\|T^{n+1}f^{(n+1)}-P_n\|,$$ where $T$ is defined as in the previous comment as $(T\phi)(x)=\int_a^x\phi(t)\,dt$, and $$f(b)-2f(\tfrac{a+b}2)+f(a) = \int_a^{(a+b)/2} \int_{x}^{(b-a)/2+x} f''(t)\,dt\,dx$$

Comment: @BrianMoehring Ah, I see, thanks.

Comment: @BrianMoehring if you'lll write it as an answer, I'll accept it. Though it is interesting what to do if there is no derivatives.